# Loading .css file from inside a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that determines the location of the desired .css file via an ajax call in `componentDidMount()`, that I want to then load before render. I've tried just adding a `<link>` element in the render return (didnt work), I've also tried directly injecting the  tag into the head using vanilla JS, but this also didnt work:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchPanelInfo().then(result => {
        console.log(this.state);

        const link = document.createElement("link");
        link.href= this.state.stylePath;
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type="text/css";
        document.head.appendChild(link);
        //const style = document.getElementById("style-direction");
        //style.href = this.state.stylePath;
    })
}
```

The shortened component:

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        token: "f0be0f7d231305a832fd1eef4bcb0e9ba18f2d65",
        error: null,
        errmsg: null,

        menuContent: null,
        stylePath: null,
        services: null,

        loading: true
    }
    isLoggedIn().then(logged => {
        //Nothing for now
    })
}
//Gets all information about the panel
async fetchPanelInfo() {
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${ENDPOINT}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        data: this.state
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
        this.setState({
            error: result.data.error,
            menuContent: result.data.menu,
            stylePath: result.data.stylePath,
            services: result.data.services,
            loading: false
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({error: err.error})
    });
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchPanelInfo().then(result => {
        console.log(this.state);

        const link = document.createElement("link");
        link.href= this.state.stylePath;
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type="text/css";
        document.head.appendChild(link);
        //const style = document.getElementById("style-direction");
        //style.href = this.state.stylePath;
    })
}

render() {
    if(this.state.loading) return null;
    return (
        <section className="panel">

            <p>Hello</p>
            <Menu items={this.state.menuContent} />
        </section>
    );
}
}
```

This is a page that `<Router>` navigates to, so I cant explicitly pre-fetch the name of the stylesheet and import separately, because the stylesheet loaded depends on the supplied token (i.e., it varies from token to token).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what didn't work? e.g. for componentDidMount method, whether link tag didn't append in head or css didn't load from url or css loaded but it didn't apply to page? `didn't work` is too vast in this context.

Comment: @Sunil in both cases, the <link> tag appeared (either in the body, or when I injected it directly to the head, in the `head`), just did nothing. I also double checked in the network tab and both instances the files loaded fine; just did not apply the style to the page.

Comment: Glad you made it work using require. But the link tag approach in componentDidMount should also work. I just tried it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sunil12738/sqg3b0hn/3/) and it works fine.

Comment: @Sunil hm, interesting - it may have something to do with the rest of the structure, unfortunately I really cant say as im fairly new to React. great to see regardless though, means I surely wasnt far off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to load and apply the dynamic .css file, as follows:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchPanelInfo().then(result => {
        console.log(this.state);

        if(this.state.stylePath === undefined) {
            require("../" + "core/data/default/styles.css");
        } else {
            require("../" + this.state.stylePath);
        }
        const React = require('react');
    })
}
```

Basically using the `require()` module.